# Cake\I18n\Time object echoes wrong hour plus daylight saving time

Tags: php, time, internationalization, cakephp-3.0, dst

I have a CakePHP 3 project with those configurations:

app.php:

```
    'defaultLocale' => env('APP_DEFAULT_LOCALE', 'pt_BR'),
    'defaultTimezone' => env('APP_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE', 'America/Sao_Paulo'),
```

bootstrap.php

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
```

When i

`echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");` it shows right date and time;

But when i

`$data = Time::now();`

and

`echo $data;`

It is shown with +1 hour because we used to add one hour for dst but this year it was canceled.

The strange part is when i debug `$data` it shows right, without +1 hour:

```
\src\Controller\TesteController.php (line 104)
object(Cake\I18n\Time) {

    'time' => '2019-10-24T15:15:07-03:00',
    'timezone' => 'America/Sao_Paulo',
    'fixedNowTime' => false

}

echo data:24/10/2019 16:15:07`
```

I've tried to add Time Zone with

`$dateTimeZoneBrasil =  new \DateTimeZone("America/Sao_Paulo");`

and

`$data = Time::now($dateTimeZoneBrasil);`

But still shows with +1 hour.

**UPDATE**

Here are the tests to reproduce the problem:

```
ini_set('intl.default_locale', 'pt_BR');
I18n::locale('pt_BR');
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
Time::setToStringFormat([\IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT]);
$time = Time::now();
debug($time);
debug((string)$time);
debug($time->i18nFormat());
debug($time->i18nFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'));
debug($time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
debug($time->getTimezone()->getTransitions(strtotime('2019-01-01'), strtotime('2020-01-01')));
phpinfo(INFO_MODULES);
```

And my results:

```
\src\Controller\TesteController.php (line 79)
object(Cake\I18n\Time) {

    'time' => '2019-10-25T09:34:37-03:00',
    'timezone' => 'America/Sao_Paulo',
    'fixedNowTime' => false

}
\src\Controller\TesteController.php (line 80)
'25/10/19 10:34'
\src\Controller\TesteController.php (line 81)
'25/10/19 10:34'
\src\Controller\TesteController.php (line 82)
'2019-10-25 10:34:37'
\src\Controller\TesteController.php (line 83)
'2019-10-25 09:34:37'
\src\Controller\TesteController.php (line 84)
[
    (int) 0 => [
        'ts' => (int) 1546308000,
        'time' => '2019-01-01T02:00:00+0000',
        'offset' => (int) -7200,
        'isdst' => true,
        'abbr' => '-02'
    ],
    (int) 1 => [
        'ts' => (int) 1550368800,
        'time' => '2019-02-17T02:00:00+0000',
        'offset' => (int) -10800,
        'isdst' => false,
        'abbr' => '-03'
    ],
    (int) 2 => [
        'ts' => (int) 1572750000,
        'time' => '2019-11-03T03:00:00+0000',
        'offset' => (int) -7200,
        'isdst' => true,
        'abbr' => '-02'
    ]
]
```

Modules:

```
date
date/time support   enabled
"Olson" Timezone Database Version   2018.7
Timezone Database   external
Default timezone    America/Sao_Paulo
Directive   Local Value Master Value
date.default_latitude   31.7667 31.7667
date.default_longitude  35.2333 35.2333
date.sunrise_zenith 90.583333   90.583333
date.sunset_zenith  90.583333   90.583333
date.timezone   America/Sao_Paulo   America/Sao_Paulo
```

Comment: You'll hardly get any (good) answers with no proper way for people to reproduce the problem (**https://gist.github.com/ndm2/df004c19e3eebe5002043a4ab385d278**). The now non-existent Brazil DST would've been scheduled for the 3rd of November, so even if your PHP installation wouldn't be aware of it being ditched, there shouldn't be any DST changes being applied right now anyways.

Comment: @ndm thanks, but i think you misunderstood, the non-existent Brazil DST started this year, Brazil used to have DST. i'll update my question with the tests you posted on gist.

Comment: I think I understood, and I think I'm correct in my assesment, the start of DST (ie `-02:00`) for Brazil was the first sunday of November (as of 2018), and the end of DST (ie `-03:00`) was the third Sunday of February. So even if DST would still exist, currently you would be in non-DST (`-03:00`) anyways. Looking at the transition information, it's correct as to what the transitions looked like, and it correctly shows that it's currently in the non-DST range.

Comment: Looking at your debug output, the regular formatting shows the correct result, ie `09:34:37`, the INTL formatting shows the incorrect result, ie `10:34:37`. I'd suggest to test it with a new, empty CakePHP project (using the most recent CakePHP version), and making sure that your INTL and ICU libraries are up to date. For me **https://gist.github.com/ndm2/231a5277a617e5d304987f13bc794947** works fine. Updating the Timezone DB also won't hurt, and I'm not sure if it's actually required, but it looks like you're missing `timelib`?

Comment: Thanks for your patience and help, part of my problem is beacuse Brasil DST starts at the 3rd sunday of October, not first sunday of November. My develpoment and production enviroments are Windows Server with apache and php 7.0 and already updated timezonedb from here: https://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb with 2018.7 that was the latest version for php 7.0

Comment: The 3rd Sunday of October date was changed in 2017, as of 2018 DST was scheduled for the 1st Sunday of November, and that's reflected in your transitions debug output that shows the change for `2019-11-03T03:00:00+0000`. Maybe you're using an outdated INTL/ICU lib that isn't aware of that change, that's my best guess, but I'm really just shooting in the dark here.

Comment: Thanks again @ndm, it's probably the problem because my environment has an old php 7.0 and maybe intl bundled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the operating system where the application is running. The time zone rules to DST are out of date. Brazil has changed its daylight saving time rules recently. But other governments can do this at any time as well.

The IANA organization maintains an up-to-date bank with time zones and other characteristics. The latest version is 2019c, published at 2019-09-11 [[1](https://www.iana.org/time-zones)].

The CAKEPHP Framework uses the PHP INTL library. The PHP INTL library uses ICU library which is part of the Linux distribution packages [[2](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/intl.requirements.php)]. And ICU library uses the IANA data.

So, an outdated version of ICU will affect how PHP handles dates.

You can check the ICU version on phpinfo() or using the command:

```
php -i | grep ICU
```

The latest version of the ICU library is 65.1 and was published on 2019-10-03 [[3](http://site.icu-project.org/download/65#TOC-ICU4C-Download)] and doesn't include IANA version 2019c. However, you can see that in the ICU repository they have already updated the zoneinfo64.txt file for future releases [[4](https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/blob/f744742e036441cbfd54b535e722dc3801ff0f63/icu4c/source/data/misc/zoneinfo64.txt)].

The latest version of ICU on CentOS 8 is 60.5 [[5](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8/BaseOS/x86_64/kickstart/Packages/)]. If you are in the Amazon AMI distribution (EC2, EBS, RDS) it will be even worse as the latest version (2018-05-14) of ICU for their distribution is 50.1.2 [[6](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/amazon-linux-ami/2018-03-packages/#i)]. The latter has a release date at 2012-12-17 [[7](http://site.icu-project.org/download/50#TOC-ICU4C-Download)]

If you are an expert in download and compile Linux services, you can compile the ICU package using the latest source code.

If you can accept an outline solution, you can lie temporarily using the **America/Fortaleza** time zone instead of **America/Sao_Paulo**. Fortaleza zone hasn't belonged to daylight saving time since 2012.

Comment: Hi William, thanks, you're right, and also i'm using America/Recife temporarily. But unfortunately i'm using PHP 7.0 on a windows server, and i'll wait for php 7.4 later this year to update. The problem is not in my SO, it's my intl+icu outdated.

Comment: Man, you saved my life!

Comment: A scientist answer! =]